# Trying to mask the text in a UIButton with a UIView

Tags: uiview, uibutton

Using iOS 13, swift 5.

Trying to mask the text in a UIButton so that I can do a gradual reveal. I created an extension, and managed to draw the view over the button, but cannot seem to work out how to mask the text shown.

This code for example clearly creates a UIView over the button, it looks like this.

[image]

Here is the code, an extension to UIButton

```
extension UIButton {
  func coverWord() {
    let frame = self.frame
    let hider = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 64)))
    hider.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hue: 1, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    self.addSubview(hider)
    self.bringSubviewToFront(hider)
}
```

Now I know that the UIView is over the button, cause I get no action if I touch the left hand side [red], but it works as expected if I touch the right side [white].

But how, do I get the stupid UIView to cover up the text. I tried creating a shape within the hidden UIView and adding to it with this code.

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 64), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
layer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
layer.fillMode = .forwards
hider.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

This works, only of course it doesn't. No it simply colors the [red] portion in green. I can still read the stupid text on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Of course as soon as I posted this question the answer dawned on me. Rather than delete it I post it here for posterity :)

```
func showWord() {

  let sizer = self.frame.size
  let hider = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: sizer))
  hider.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

  let sub = self.titleLabel
  sub!.addSubview(hider)
  sub!.bringSubviewToFront(hider)

  self.addSubview(hider)
  self.bringSubviewToFront(hider)

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations: {

    hider.alpha = 0
  }) { ( _ ) in
    hider.removeFromSuperview()
 }
}
```

The text in the UIButton is a UILabel within it. I need to add the UIView to it to hide the label AND to the button to mask the action when it is pressed.

There is a view in Xcode that shows you the sublayers. That is all I needed to do to figure the solution.

Here is a second version that acts like a pair of curtains, coloured in red and green for good measure.

```
func splitWord() {
  let sizer = self.frame.size
  print("sizer",sizer)
  let hider0 = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size:sizer))


  let hider1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 18, height: 64)))
  let hider2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 18, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 18, height: 64)))
  hider1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  hider2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
  hider0.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

  let sub = self.titleLabel
  let subs = sub?.frame.size
  print("sub",subs)
  sub?.insertSubview(hider1, at: 1)
  sub?.insertSubview(hider2, at: 2)
  self.insertSubview(hider0, at: 1)

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 4, animations: {
    hider1.center = CGPoint(x: -18, y: 0)
    hider2.center = CGPoint(x: 54, y: 0)
  }) { (_) in
    hider0.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

Obviously the sizes shown here -18 and 54 are linked to the size of the label which says "next" in my case. Room for improvement I know, but its late here and time for bed.